# How to pipe a stream to a file descriptor in node?

Tags: node.js, posix, file-descriptor

I'm writing a cli in node, I want to open the users $EDITOR to edit data that is read from a stream (an http response IncomingMessage).

How can I send the data to a file descriptor?

In bash I could write this:

```sh
$EDITOR <(curl $url)
```

or

```sh
$DIFF <(curl $url_1) <(curl $url_2)
```

`<(curl $url)` expands to something like `/proc/self/fd/11`

```sh
echo <(curl $url)
/proc/self/fd/11
```

But how would I write it in javascript?

```
import cp from 'child_process'
const fisrt = request(...);
const second = require(...);
const first_fd = ???;
const second_fd = ???;

const proc = cp.spawn(process.env.DIFF, [first_fd, second_fd] { stdio: 'inherit' });
```

Okay, if `stream` is backed by a socket or fd you can pass it to `options.stdio`, but what if it isn't, what if it's a transform stream?

> [options.stdio](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_stdio)
>    object - Share a readable or writable stream that refers to a tty, file, socket, or a pipe with the child process. The stream's underlying file descriptor is duplicated in the child process to the fd that corresponds to the index in the stdio array. The stream must have an underlying descriptor (file streams do not until the 'open' event has occurred).

Yes I could create a temp file but can I do it without one?

Comment: So are you trying to open your favorite editor from a javascript code in terminal? What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I want to open an interactive editor or diff program from a scripted workflow.

Specifically I am requesting two tar.gz files, uncompressing them, iterating over the entries of each archive, and I want to open similar files from each archive in a `diff` program. Preferably without explicitly writing anything to disk or creating temp files.

Comment: Why do you have to use `diff` in bash? You can use the same program in library format in node: https://www.npmjs.com/package/diff

Comment: I want to open any diff tool, `diff`, `vimdiff`, `meld`, or `git diff --no-index`.

Answer (score 0):

You can stream a downloaded content into vim text editor in your terminal with the following nodejs code:

```js
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const request = require('request');
// 
request({
    url: 'https://google.com' 
}, function (err, res, body) { 
    const vi = spawn('vi', ['-'], { stdio: ['pipe', process.stdout, process.stderr] });

    vi.stdin.write(body);
    vi.stdin.end();
});
```

Then from your terminal if you execute this code, it will download google's html and let you edit and save it in a file. You can use `:w myfile.txt` to save to a file in vim.

Further reading on this matter: https://2ality.com/2018/05/child-process-streams.html

Comment: `-` is a convention, not a os behavior right? I want the editor that is opened to be user configurable, and I don't think all programs will read from stdin when passed `-`. How could I open _two_ files?

Comment: About the `-` being convention; the comment in this answer says so: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/738

Comment: Opening 2 files such as `diff <(curl $url_1) <(curl $url_2)` is something I could not achieve. I hope it is possible and somebody can show it here.

Answer (score 0):

```
const { spawnSync } = require('child_process');

const string_1 = 'foo';
const string_2 = 'foobar';

const command = 'diff';
const args = [
    '--unified',
    `<(echo "${string_1}")`,
    `<(echo "${string_2}")`,
];
const options = {
    'shell': '/bin/bash',
};

const diff = spawnSync(command, args, options);
console.log(diff.stdout.toString());
```

Comment: Could you clarify how this solves the question being asked?

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.